# how to make my image behind my labels?

Tags: ios, image, swift, struct

my label and toolbar disappear from the view when i run the app hidden behind my image

**this is my viewdidload code**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    var tiger1 = Tigers()
    tiger1.name = "BengalTiger"
    tiger1.age = 1
    tiger1.breed = "Bengal"
    tiger1.fact = "live in the bengal area"
    tiger1.image = UIImage(named: "BengalTiger.jpg")!


    self.nameLabel.text = tiger1.name
    self.ageLabel.text = String(tiger1.age)
    self.breedLabel.text = tiger1.breed
    self.factLabel.text = tiger1.fact
    self.imageView.image = tiger1.image


    tigersArray.append(tiger1)



}
```

**and this is my struct:**

```
struct Tigers {

var image = UIImage(named: "")
var name = ""
var age = 0
var breed = ""
var fact = ""
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
self.view.sendSubviewToBack(imageView)
```

and that will put it behind your other views

Here you see the imageView in the back of the other view elements, so the button and label will be shown on top of the image view:

[image]

Below you see the elements are behind the image view so they will be covered up by the image.

[image]

You can arrange elements in the document outline by dragging them up and down.

Comment: Or you could use the document outline to push it back

Comment: the OP didn't mention using a storyboard but if the op is using one that would work

Comment: as Epic stated you can move the imageView in the view hierarchy in the document online of your storyboard, I will update my answer to show you

Comment: when i set a background image from the utilities this problem appear then when i drag the image from the document outline down and then up to it's initial place the problem solved...

Comment: If you're using the Storyboard for everything you should put the imageView in the back first, then always add your other elements on top of it

Answer (score 2):

Natives metods

```
insertSubview:(UIView *) aboveSubview:(UIView *)
```

or

```
insertSubview:(UIView *) belowSubview:(UIView *)
```

Comment: am a little bit newbie you make me remember a question that i find all the time which is a native app i google it but i always prefer the stackoverflow answer ...

Comment: Sorry i don't understand your question.

Comment: ok, for example UIView have own metods, these methods were written by Apple - this is native/standard/reference/ methods

Comment: - (void)addSubview:(UIView *)view; - for example you can use it [self.view addSubview self.anotherView];